# Dell precision 5560 can't do 3 monitors. RTX card not primary graphic controller

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, dell-precision

I have a dell precision 5560 with an i9 and a build in rtx a2000 graphics card.

I want to connect 3 monitors to this laptop. I hooked up a docking station to it that supports 2 monitors and the third one I directly connected to the notebook with the included hdmi to usb-c adapter.

The problem is that only 2 monitors are working. Which monitor is active depenteds on the order of connecting them.

So I googled a lot and found [this threat](https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/Precision-7510-won-t-do-3-external-monitors/td-p/7691907) where this is explaned:

> our issue may be with the Intel integrated graphics.  By default all video output is routed through and handled by the Intel graphics.
>
> Go into your Bios and  go to the Graphics options.
> Tick the checkbox for "Discrete Graphics Controller Direct Output Mode"  This will route all external displays directly through the Nvidia GPU.
>
> The other option would be to un-check the "Enable Switchable Graphics" option.  This will allow your Nvidia Quadro to be the only GPU that the computer uses. (I am using this option for my Precision 7710)

So I went into the BIOS to change this setting but I don't have this setting in the bios.

I also found [another page](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000144475/how-to-connect-multiple-monitors-to-your-dell-precision-mobile-m4600-m4700-m4800-m6600-m6700-and-m6800-system) that explanes how to activate 3 monitors. There it is said that you need to get into the nvidia control panel and chage the display settings. But sadly I only have the '3d options' in the control panel and nothing else.

When google how get the display option back, the solution is also to change the primary graphics controller to the rtx card.

Do you have any idea what I can do now to get the 3 monitor working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the information you found simply does not apply to your device. Instead, check the correct document: [precision-15-5560-laptop_owners-manual_en-us.pdf](https://dl.dell.com/topicspdf/precision-15-5560-laptop_owners-manual_en-us.pdf). On page 19, you can find the “Multiple display support matrix”. It’s supposed to relay how multiple displays can work.

My interpretation: To get the number of displays you want, you must use a Thunderbolt docking station. Most docking stations are *not* using a Thunderbolt connection but only USB-C with DisplayPort Alt Mode.

And indeed, when using my TB16 (Thunderbolt, connected to 2 2560×1440 displays) docking station and the WD15 (DisplayPort Alt Mode, connected to 2 1920×1080 displays) docking station from the neighboring table, I can drive four displays in total with my Precision 5560. That means one of the smaller displays remains off so my laptop display can remain on.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. I didn't know that the included display adapter does not work with thunderbolt but only with the displayPort alt mode usb-c port..